# A DCT function I wrote in Octave sometimes returns undefined values

Tags: matlab, octave, dct

I'm taking a 8x8 chunk of a greyscale image I got and I have to use matlab or octave to apply a 2D-DCT to it. I wrote a simple 1D-DCT function that I plan on just applying twice to get my answer, but when I try running the function I get undefined values.

I've tried reseting my variables and looked over the code and the chapter in my textbook that goes over DCT but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
function C=dct(xb, n)
   for i=1:n
      for j=1:n
        xb(i,j)=cos((i-1)*(2*j-1)*pi/(2*n));
      endfor
   endfor
 xb=sqrt(2/n)*xb;
 xb(1,:)=xb(1,:)/sqrt(2);
endfunction
```

I was expecting to get an 8x8 array of the DCT of the vector I fed in, but instead I got this

> > xb = dct(xb, 8)
> >     warning: dct: some elements in list of return values are undefined
> >     warning: called from
> >         dct at line 9 column 9
> >     xb =

Comment: You never assign a value to the return variable `C`.

Comment: thank you! Thats the problem